# WooCommerce webhook parsing

Tags: php, json, wordpress, google-apps-script, woocommerce

Trying to parse the input JSON from the Woocommerce Webhook to Google Spreadsheet via Google App Script.

Used this one :

```
function doPost(request) {     

var json = request.postData.getDataAsString(); 
var obj = JSON.parse(json);     


// getting some of the Woocommerce data just as an example
// Hook was fired after order.created
var id = obj.order.id;
var orderNumber = obj.order.order_number;
var payMethod = obj.order.payment_details.method_title;    


// write data in a document, not useful, but straightforward for testing   

var doc =     DocumentApp.openById('myDocumentId');
doc.appendParagraph("Id: " + id);
doc.appendParagraph("orderNumber: " + orderNumber);
doc.appendParagraph("payMethod: " + payMethod);

}
```

But receive nothing into the Google Sheets.

---

And with this one:

```
function doPost(request) {

  var content = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents);

  var row = [];
  for (var elem in content) {
      row.push(content[elem]);
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET ID")
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.appendRow(row);

  var result = {"result":"ok"};

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

It's receiving data, but it's not parsed:

[image: import json]

Is there anyway to fix this and make the data in sheet viewable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer on my question at https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
thanks to **Alexander Ivanov**

The main thing why the woocommerce webhook not parsed is that the JSON is not valid when WC send it to the spreadsheet macros.

And sheet posting it as one element `{order:{}}`

so we need to edit the code like this :

```
var content = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents)[0];
```

or like this (in my case):

```
var content = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents)['order'];
```

in case we have no idea what data will be received, we may try to determine the value:

```
function doPost(request) {
  var result = {
    result: undefined
  };
  try {
    var content = JSON.parse(request.postData.contents);
    var row = [];
    if (content.hasOwnProperty('order')) {
      for (var elem in content['order']) {
        row.push(content['order'][elem]);
      }
    } else {
      row.push(request.postData.contents);
    }
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET ID')
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.appendRow(row);
    result.result = 'ok';
  } catch (err) {
    result.result = 'err';
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```